# iText formatting problems

Tags: java, pdf, itext

**Context**

I've been working on dynamic PDF generation for a while now, and I've come across my final requirement. Alas, it's a nightmare. I'm using the *iText* library, version 2.1.7.

I'm basically trying to get a formatting like the top row (which I just mocked up in paint). The other rows are how it looks at the moment, but I'm having some real trouble with getting them to line up properly!

[image]

**Code**

The code being used to generate each color coded block is here:

```
        String currentPrice = p.getPrice();
        String timeStr = p.getTime();         
        Chunk price = new Chunk(currentPrice);
        Chunk time = (Chunk) generatePdfElement("Timestamp", timeStr);

        if (priceDbl > lastPrice) {
             // set color to blue.
             price.setBackground(WebColors.getRGBColor("#7777FF"));
             time.setBackground(WebColors.getRGBColor("#7777FF"));
        } else if (priceDbl < lastPrice) {
             // set to red.
             price.setBackground(WebColors.getRGBColor("#FF0000"));
             time.setBackground(WebColors.getRGBColor("#FF0000"));
        }

        Paragraph pricePara = new Paragraph();
        pricePara.add(price);
        pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
        pricePara.add(time);
        pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
        // Add the new price data to the list of all the prices for this cell.
        allPrices.add(pricePara);
```

`allPrices` is then added to a paragraph and put into the cell:

```
    Paragraph pricesCellValue = new Paragraph();
    pricesCellValue.addAll(allPrices);
    PdfPCell pricesCell = new PdfPCell(pricesCellValue);
    pricesCell.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor(getRowStr()));
    selectionsTable.addCell(pricesCell);
    // Add each cell to the table to create the row.
```

**The approaches I've tried**

I tried the obvious, which was removing the last breakline from each `Chunk`. This didn't work, and it just looked exactly the same, although each `Chunk` was closer together.

I also tried changing from `Paragraph` to `Phrase`, which means the code looked like this:

```
  Phrase pricePara = new Phrase();
  pricePara.add(price);
  pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
  pricePara.add(time);
  //pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
  // Add the new price data to the list of all the prices for this cell.
  allPrices.add(pricePara);
```

And this was the result:

[image]

So now I'm fresh out of ideas! Does anyone else have any suggestions, or some experience with iText in this area?

**Edit**

Just for clarity, `generateBreakLine()` generates a new empty `Paragraph` object.

Comment: 1. I usually don't answer question from people who deliberately choose to use obsolete software (see http://lowagie.com/itext2 ). 2. Why don't you try using a nested table?

Comment: Ah, hello creator of the obsolete software I'm using. I'll have a look into nested tables; would you mind posting that as an answer so I can mark it as correct if it works out for me?

Comment: Or, if it works, you can post it as an answer for further reference and mark it as accepted ;-)

Comment: Well I thought I'd be nice considering you'd got me to my answer, but sure. I can do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a nested `PdfPTable` in the last cell, to format the positioning of each `Phrase`. Works like a dream!